# Add updated_at column in postgres table using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

**Short Description:** I want to add `insertion_date` and `last_update` columns to a table in a Postgresql database using SQLalchemy ORM. I followed the documentation and the examples on SO, but it didn't work for me.

Here is my example:

base.py

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

movie_model.py

```
from __future__ import annotations
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import func
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Column
from typing import Optional, Dict, Union
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import String, Date, DateTime, Integer


class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movies'
    movie_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    movie_name = Column(String)
    release_date = Column(Date)
    movie_revenue = Column(Integer)
    last_update = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)
    insertion_date = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())

    # __mapper_args__ = {"eager_defaults": True}

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(movie_dict: Dict[str, Union[str, int, datetime]]) -> Optional[Movie]:
        if not movie_dict:
            return None
        return Movie(
            movie_id=movie_dict.get('movie_id'),
            movie_name=movie_dict.get('movie_name'),
            release_date=movie_dict.get('release_date'),
            movie_revenue=movie_dict.get('movie_revenue')
        )
```

db_manager.py

```
from movie_model import Movie
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
from typing import List


class DBManager:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session
        self.columns = Movie.__table__.columns.keys()
        self.primary_key = inspect(Movie).primary_key[0]
        self.primary_key_name = self.primary_key.name

    def add_many_on_conflict_do_update(self, movies: List[Movie]) -> None:
        # Used self.columns[:-2] to exclude the last two columns (last_update and insertion_date) from the explicit insertion, so the ORM handles it
        # on its own as mentioned here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.onupdate.
        statement = insert(Movie.__table__).values([{attr: getattr(movie, attr) for attr in self.columns[:-2]} for movie in movies])

        statement = statement.on_conflict_do_update(
            index_elements=[self.primary_key_name], set_={attr: getattr(statement.excluded, attr) for attr in self.columns[:-2]}
        )

        self.session.execute(statement)
        self.session.commit()

    def get_all(self) -> List[Movie]:
        return self.session.query(Movie).all()
```

main.py

```
from movie_model import Movie
from db_manager import DBManager
import datetime
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session


def main():
    db_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://db_user:password@localhost:5432/db_name"
    engine = create_engine(db_string, echo=False)
    session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)

    movie1 = {
        'movie_id': '1',
        'movie_name': 'movie1',
        'release_date': datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-09-23', '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
        'movie_revenue': 1000
    }

    movie2 = {
        'movie_id': '2',
        'movie_name': 'movie2',
        'release_date': datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-09-23', '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
        'movie_revenue': 2000
    }

    movie3 = {
        'movie_id': '3',
        'movie_name': 'movie3',
        'release_date': datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-09-24', '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
        'movie_revenue': 3000
    }

    movie4 = {
        'movie_id': '4',
        'movie_name': 'movie4',
        'release_date': datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-09-24', '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
        'movie_revenue': 4000
    }

    movies = [movie1, movie2, movie3, movie4]
    movies_models = []
    for movie in movies:
        movies_models.append(Movie.from_dict(movie))

    db_manager = DBManager(session=session)
    db_manager.add_many_on_conflict_do_update(movies_models)

    retrieved_movies = db_manager.get_all()
    for movie in retrieved_movies:
        print(movie.last_update)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Packages:**

```
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.24
```

**Postgres version: ** 12.

When I run `python main.py` the `insertion_date` is inserted properly even if I run it for many times adding new movie each time. But the `last_update` is only inserted the first time I add a movie, while it is expected to be updated whenever an update is applied to the already inserted movie.
I tried replacing `self.columns[:-2]` by `self.columns[:-1]` or by `self.columns` in the insertion statement and/or in the `_set` parameter. But it ended up that `last_update` column is `null` or it is being updated every time I run `main.py` even if there are no updates/insertions to apply.

I also replaced `onupdate` by `server_onupdate` and `datetime.datetime.now` by `func.now()` in `movie_model.py` but nothing worked.

I even added `__mapper_args__ = {"eager_defaults": True}` to `Movie()` in `movie_model.py` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52393488/8128190) but still didn't work.

I checked the following questions on SO but nothing worked too:
[- Is possible to create Column in SQLAlchemy which is going to be automatically populated with time when it inserted/updated last time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978554/is-possible-to-create-column-in-sqlalchemy-which-is-going-to-be-automatically-po)
[- onupdate not overridinig current datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410315/onupdate-not-overridinig-current-datetime-value)

Any suggestions to make it work?

**Edit for clarification:**
What I am looking for is to make the `last_update` column get updated with the time of the transaction whenever a row is updated (using `on_conflict_do_update`).

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the behaviour in `on_conflict_do_update`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I added an edit to clarify what I am asking for exactly which is to get the `last_update` column updated every time a row from the table is updated. The row update here is done using `on_conflict_do_update`.

Comment: See warning at the end of [this section](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#the-set-clause): when using Postgres' `ON CONFLICT` you need to do provide the value yourself, column defaults won't work.

Comment: That makes sense, so I tried to provide the value myself in the `_set` parameter by including the `last_update` value using `self.columns[:-1]`. But this kept updating the column every time even if there are no updates in the other fields. (I think this can be explained by: including the value of the `last_update` column in the `_set` argument has triggered the `on_conflict_do_update()` so it will keep updating the row as long as I run it).